# applescript and Fetch

Tags: applescript

I was going to use the Automator to run some remote to local backups but will need to do some looping so I thought that Applescript would be a better choice.  As a complete newbie to Applescript, my first attempt to download all files from a given folder with specific characteristics resulted in an error:

```
set today to current date
set yesterday to (today - 1)
tell application "Fetch"
    activate
    open remote folder "/public_html/books/book_3/_thumbs/Images"
    copy every file of folder to beginning of alias "MacintoshHD:Users:franciscaparedes:Desktop:untitled folder:"
whose modification date is greater than yesterday
end tell
```

Here's my error:
 `Fetch got an error: Can’t set beginning of alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:franciscaparedes:Desktop:untitled folder:\" whose «class pMod» > date \"Monday, December 24, 2012 6:37:17 AM\" to every file of folder." number -10006 from insertion point 1 of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:franciscaparedes:Desktop:untitled folder:" whose modification date > date "Monday, December 24, 2012 6:37:17 AM"`

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

-Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

I only had a quick look at this. Which means this most likely can be mad simpler.

The Fetch library is IMO not the well explained. But I think that of most applescript libraries.

But You should read the libraries. This will help you understand what is scriptable in the application and the syntax to use.

To access the library of an app. In Applescript Editor. Go to the Windows->library menu.
This will open the libraries window. If you see your app in there double click it. A new library will open with all the syntax and commands you can use.

Don't get exited when you see it and start thinking oh yes baby this is good the world is mine..hahaha. Because you will soon discover it takes a bit of time to workout how to put it all together.

If your app is not in the library window. Locate the app in finder and drag and drop it onto it. If it is scriptable it will be added to the library.

Also read  [Apples Applescript  Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptx/Concepts/work_with_as.html)

```
set today to current date
set number_of_days to 1

tell application "Fetch"
    activate

    #open a shortcut
    open shortcut "Shortcut Name"
    #set the remote window to your remote path
    open remote folder "/public_html/books/book_3/_thumbs/Images"

    #get the properties of every file in remote window. This will give use the modified date and url of each file
    set props to properties of remote items of transfer window 1

    #iterate through the files
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in props
        # one of the items
        set this_item to item i of props
        #get its modification date
        set modDate to modification date of this_item
        # compare the dtae by using number of days
        set TimeDiff to (today - modDate) -- the difference in seconds
        set DaysOut to (TimeDiff div days) -- the number of days out

        if DaysOut is greater than number_of_days then
            #use the files url to download it to the POSIX file path of you folder
            download url (url of this_item) to file "MacintoshHD:Users:franciscaparedes:Desktop:untitled folder:"
        end if

    end repeat

end tell
```

Comment: Thanks @markhunte.  This really helped set me on the right track!

Comment: No problem. Does this answer your question or was there more ?